# Make an existing field as an autocomplete field in node form

Tags: 6

I have created a content type and in this node form i have a cck field 'name'. I want to alter this node form and change attributes of the 'name' field and add     `'#autocomplete_path' => "taguser/{$node->vid}/autocomplete",` to it. But i am unable to do it. Can you please let me know how to do it.

Comment: Hacker, completely unrelated, and I am just curious, what is your native language?

Comment: Blue928 - how is it unrelated???

Comment: By unrelated, I mean my comment does not have anything to do with your question. Sometimes in your posts the English is a little unclear. I am not sure if it against SE policy as to what language you post in, but perhaps if you also posted in your native language under the English those of us who may speak it may get a better idea  as to what you are asking. I think that maybe the reason sometimes you get a few down votes, so it may be helpful

Comment: @blue928 To the best of my knowledge questions on English-speaking Stack Exchange sites are expected to be in English (although I must admit I can't find a reference for that right now). Any time I've seen foreign script in a question it has either been translated by a benevolent passer-by, or edited out of the question altogether